# Unrelated Range Interfering with Values of other Ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm having a weird issue where 2 completely unrelated ranges within a Google Sheet seem to be interfering with and changing the values of some other ranges that should have no correlation to them.

**Details:**

Within the spreadsheet there are 2 ranges that are intended to be used to store a value completely unrelated to the rest of the sheet. Let's call them X & Y. Their ranges or values have not been declared as variables since they will not be used by the rest of the script. If their value is left as undefined the rest of the script works perfectly.

However, if values have been entered, a group of 5 other ranges and their values are interfered with. These 5 ranges store values that are used by a simple mathematical equation. 3 of the ranges are nothing more than the results of the formula while the other 2 are actually in the formula being used. Let's call them var A & B. Therefore adjusting the numerical value of A/B will output new values displayed to the 3 results ranges. This equation is nested within a function that is called whenever the values for A/B are detected to have changed by an onEdit function.

Within the equation itself or it's containing function there are no references to the ranges or values of X/Y. There is no code within the onEdit that listens for interaction with X/Y. The rest of the script should know nothing about X/Y and editing their value should not result in anything other than a simple change of the values stored within them.

However this is not the case. As mentioned above, when there are X/Y values present then the A/B equation is interfered with and the results of the formula change as well as the values of A/B.

I have combed through the code line by line but cannot see how this could be happening since there are no references to either the ranges or the values of X/Y. I am at a complete loss on what is happening here.

Has anybody else seen something like this before.... What am I missing here ?

Comment: It would seem that either there is a bug in the code, or that the values in the ranges depend on each other through spreadsheet formulas, perhaps an array formula or an array expression. Consider sharing the code and a [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: As @doubleunary said, consider sharing the document with the code so that we can study your problem in a practical way. In case you have compromised data, create a new one with random data reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You guys were right. While trying to strip down the code and provide a sample sheet for you to look at I noticed the issue disappeared. So I reverse engineered the code adding things back in and found a loop in one of the functions. Corrected that and all is fine. Thanks for the assistance !!!